# Strange behaviour with TCP sockets in thread

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock

We have an application where we send data through TCP sockets. We use 8 TCP connections for this. The socket send and receive is called in a background thread. There is just one thread which iterates over the array of sockets to send data through all of them (sequential).

The code in sender thread is something like:

```
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    nBytesWrriten = send (tcpsock[i], data2, nleft, 0))
    //error handling and process more data

}
```

and the receiver thread is like:

```
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    sz[i] = recv (tcpsock[i], data, MAX_UDT_SIZE, 0);
    //process data
}
```

Everything works fine and the data gets transferred, but sometimes it just takes too long.
On checking logs, I found that in most cases, the sender thread works just fine , but sometimes, there is a huge delay in timestamps(sometimes more than a second) before and after 'send' call.

All of the send and receive action is taking place in a worker thread. Is it something to do with pre-emption of the thread just before/on send call? Can I avoid the pre-emption of the thread just before the send call? Or is it that the receiver thread has not received the data on the socket while send it ready with more data, and therefore it causes the delay?

How do I optimize this as it is taking too long to send data?

Thanks

Comment: You can use tools like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to check if there are any delays on a lower level than your application.

Comment: Are your sockets no-blocking (`O_NONBLOCK`)?  If not, the `send()` call won't return until all the data has been accepted by the local TCP stack (which is only somewhat related to what goes out on the wire and may be immediate or may take some time).  Including a wireshark/tcpdump trace might help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use non-blocking sockets for sending. What might be happening is that one (or more than one) cannot send right away, so it waits until it can send some data, maybe buffers full or whatever.

Using non-blocking sockets it won't stop, but you must check that the data was not sent to some sockets and try again later.

Comment: @Default and he said the send delays (block) and is only one thread.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `select` on each socket before the send to see if you can write without blocking, otherwise you'll block the sends on the other sockets.  You'll want to do the same thing on the read side or the lack of readability of one could block available read on others.

Comment: From a design perspective, what you ought to do is do a `select` on ALL of the sockets at once, on both ends, and do your loop writes and reads on each that is ready.  That would prevent spin-polling if all sockets are not ready...